# Core Data MOC change not triggered when editing certain values

Tags: objective-c, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview

In my app I have two `NSOutlineView` tables. My represented objects have dynamic attributes, so I have to add columns dynamically.
This is what the objects look like:

[Instance properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8WK5.png)

I use Core Data and Cocoa bindings to display and edit the values.

I can display all the attributes in the outline view, and (seemingly) edit them, too, but only certain properties trigger an `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`. That means, that the data is not saved for certain columns -- unless I modify a value in a correctly working column, too. In that case, *all* data is subsequently saved, even the ones that did not trigger the context change.

This is a correctly working column:

```
NSTableColumn *nameColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Name"];
nameColumn.title = @"Name";
nameColumn.width = 200;
[self.instancesOutlineView addTableColumn:nameColumn];
[nameColumn bind:NSValueBinding
        toObject:self.instancesTreeController
     withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.name"
         options:nil];
```

However, the columns which are created from the `NSDictionary`property do not trigger the context change:

```
NSTreeNode *selectedNode = [self.typesOutlineView itemAtRow:[self.typesOutlineView selectedRow]];
InstanceType *it = (InstanceType *)[selectedNode representedObject];

// Get Instance Dynamic Attributes dictionary
Instance *i = it.instances.anyObject;
NSDictionary *instanceDynAtts = i.dynamicAttributes;
for (NSString *key in instanceDynAtts) {

    NSTableColumn *column = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:key];
    column.title = key;
    [self.instancesOutlineView addTableColumn:column];
    NSString *keyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.dynamicAttributes.%@.value", key];
    [column bind:NSValueBinding 
        toObject:self.instancesTreeController 
     withKeyPath:keyPath
         options:nil];

}
```

What could be the problem here? Is there a way to force saving the context, even if it hasn't changed?

Comment: I'm guessing: Core Data observes the modeled properties and `dynamicAttributes` doesn't change. `NSManagedObjectContext` has a `save` method.